# align button on the right side

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to align the `X` button to be on the right side next to the `User`. However, `X` falls into a new line.

Here is what I have tried.

```html
<b>ID: </b><ul id="user_id" name="user_id"> User 
<button type="button" style="display:block;>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">X</button></ul>
```

any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `ul > li` semantics correct first. Then, since `button` is by default `display-inline`, remove the `block` style, and it should come next without any additional css.

```html
<b>ID: </b>
<ul id="user_id" name="user_id">
  <li>
    User
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @hellomynameis please feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block` and your X will move to the right side (be aligned in the same row).